# Software for animating card game

Tags: windows, gratis, animation

I've created a card game and wanted to make a video tutorial.

I have all the card images ready (as PDFs, which I can easily convert), and wanted to know what the best software would be to do this?

I don't need any people in the animation, just a table, cards, and maybe text but I can add that later.

It needs to be :

- Windows 10 compatible
- Free
- Easy to learn
- Publishable to video

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I thought Blender may be good but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) is probably the best. Free, and it competes with top tier software like [3DS Max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_3ds_Max) and [Maya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autodesk_Maya).

But if you are looking for an alternative, you could try [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28game_engine%29) or [Unreal Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine). While they are game engines at heart, they do provide a few animating toolset. Coupled with a physics engine, maybe they might be more suited to your use case.